# How to Add and Update entries in Tables using Angular2 and Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a table in which entries are present. i have an edit popup which functions both like adding and editing. Now if i edit the content of one row in popup it is showing what i am typing in Table. The table must have the previous value only once i click save, then it must get updated with the edited entry.

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input type="text" mdInput name="employeeDashboardID" placeholder="EmployDashboard Id" #updated [(value)]="user.employeeDashboardID" required>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Save and Cancel Buttons -->
                <div md-theme="reports" class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div layout-align="end center" layout="row">
                        <button md-raised-button class="md-raised color-white" (click)="editUser.hide()" style="width: 45%;margin: 10px 5px;background-color: #FF5252;">Cancel</button>
                        <button md-raised-button class="md-raised color-white" (click)="editedUser(updated,user)" [disabled]="!editForm.form.valid" style="width: 45%;margin: 10px 5px;">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Ts code:

```
/* edit User */
edit(user:any) {
  this.user = user;
  this.editUser.show();
}
/* Function to edit User successfully */
editedUser(updated:any,user:any) {
  console.log(user);
  console.log(updated);
  var data = {
    user_id: user.users._id,
    employee_id: user.employeeDashboardID
  }

 this.ApiService
     .changeUser(data)
     .subscribe(
       users => {
         this.toasterService.pop('success', 'updated successfully');
         this.editUser.hide();
         /* Get All Users */
           this.ApiService
               .getUsers()
               .subscribe(
                 users => {
                   this.loading = false;
                   users.sort(function(a:any, b:any) {
                         return (a._id - b._id);
                       });
                   this.users = users;
                   this.user = new User();
                 },error => {
                   console.log(error);
                 })
      },error => {
          this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Something went wrong!');
      })
}
```

Comment: if u want value should update after click the save button, then remove the two way binding .

Comment: Thanks for response.. can you please help me.. i had removed ngmodel and wrote value

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a copy of the user, then bind that copy to your popup. Then on save you can update the original user and on cancel, just abandon the copy:

```
edit(user:any) {
  this.currentEditUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)); //This is one way to make a copy, there are others such as Object.assign()
  this.editUser.show();
}
```

So bind your popup to currentEditUser and pass currentEditUser into your `editedUser(updated:any,user:any)` method

Comment: Thanks for response.. I will try

Comment: Which part isn't working? Does it show the user in the popup and still allow updating the fields? Can you post a full example on plunker?

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that editUser was already being used. In my example, the first line should be: this.currentEditUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));

Comment: So then use currentEditUser for your binding in the HTML etc, I've updated the example

Comment: Did this resolve your issue? If so, please mark it as the correct answer